# Why is my SUMIF function not working with formatted table?

Tags: excel-formula

I want to create a formula to sum 2020 visits only, but I don't know why this does not work:
=SUMIF(Web_Metrics[Date],YEAR(Web_Metrics[@Date])=2020,Web_Metrics[amazon.com - Visits])

I have tried without the @, with the year in "2020" but with no success

Thanks for your help

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU59q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do changes to the data in the ranges.  SUMIF takes a range and not an array which is what `YEAR(Web_Metrics[@Date])` does.

You will need to use SUMIFS and bracket the dates:

```
=SUMIFS(Web_Metrics[amazon.com - Visits],Web_Metrics[Date],">="&DATE(2020,1,1),Web_Metrics[Date],"<"&DATE(2021,1,1))
```